# Is there a more elegant way to achieve a "cheat code" implementation for a game in C++?

Tags: c++, refactoring

I have been learning C++ by diving into a project, a simple 2d game. I have attempted to implement a set of cheats but I'm seriously novice at string manipulation. I'm sure there would be a more elegant way to achieve what I would like than my code below.

As requested, `stringBuffer` is just a string that contains the last 12 pressed characters. I prepend it because it's trimmed at the end later with resize, and hence my cheats have to be backwards. I'm very much a noob at string manipulation, and I know something is wrong here, which I why I asked for it to be looked at and possibly improved.

```
//The following code is in my keyPressed function
cheatBuffer = (char)key + cheatBuffer;
cheatBuffer.resize(12);
string tempBuffer;
string cheats[3] = {"1taehc","2taehc","3taehc"};
for(int i = 0;i < 3;i++){
    tempBuffer = cheatBuffer;
    tempBuffer.resize(cheats[i].size());
    if(cheats[i] == tempBuffer){
        switch(i){
            case 1:
                //activate cheat 1
                break;
            case 2:
                //active cheat 2
                break;
            case 3:
                //active cheat 3
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

The codes are "cheat1", "cheat2" and "cheat3" respectively. I can't help thinking that this could be a lot better. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What about using std::map<std::string, std::tr1::function<> > And then just myCheats["enteredCode"]();

Comment: I think you need to flesh this question out a bit more.  Mainly you need to explain what cheatBuffer is and what you're trying to do with it.  Like, why are you appending the character to the beginning rather than the end?

Comment: Not so fast -- what if the entered code is not a match?

Comment: It was just an example, you could use std::map's find before to check whether there is value assigned to a key.

Comment: @Palmik, I'm quite novice, I would be very interested to see how this works if you could elaborate with a code example in the answers section.

Comment: What are you trying to do with `cheatBuffer = (char)key + cheatBuffer; `? Are you prepending the string with a character? Is `key` a character already? (Must make sure you aren't misunderstanding a lexical cast.)

Comment: @milypostman, I have added a bit of the body of the question.

Comment: @chrisaycock It's actually an integer which corresponds to the characters key code.

Comment: @Sam152 sure, give me a minute :)

Comment: @Sam152 I thought that was the case. In C++, you can't just convert an `int` to a `char` and let the compiler figure-out the details. You actually have manipulate the ASCII. The easiest way for your case is `char(key)+'0'`, which will give you the value you want.

Comment: @chrisaycock Interesting, it seemed natural and just worked so naturally I assumed it was fine. I will have a look into what you are saying and make the appropriate adjustments.

Comment: @Sam152 Yeah, and the compiler won't even alert you to the error in this case! In particular, what you want is a type of *lexical cast*. C++ can be tricky if you try to use it like PHP. Instead, think of it as assembly; `key` is just some number and has to be treated as such.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to consider using:

`std::map<std::string, std::function<void ()>>` (If you can use C++0x)

`std::map<std::string, std::tr1::function<void ()>>` (If you can use TR1)

`std::map<std::string, boost::function<void ()>>` (If you can use Boost)

(Of course, the signature of the function can differ)

Example using C++0x

```
#include <map>
#include <functional>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

typedef std::map<std::string, std::function<void ()>> cheat_map;

inline void cheat1()
{
    std::cout << "cheat 1 used!" << std::endl;
}

inline void cheat2()
{
    std::cout << "cheat 2 used!" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    cheat_map myCheats;
    myCheats.insert(std::pair<std::string, std::function<void ()>>("cheat1", std::function<void ()>(cheat1)));
    myCheats.insert(std::pair<std::string, std::function<void ()>>("cheat2", std::function<void ()>(cheat2)));

    std::string buffer;
    while (std::getline(std::cin, buffer)) {
        if (!std::cin.good()) {
            break;
        }

        cheat_map::iterator itr = myCheats.find(buffer);
        if (itr != myCheats.end()) {
            myCheats[buffer]();
        }
    }
}
```

Input:

```
notourcheat
cheat1
cheat2
cheat1
```

Output:

```
cheat 1 used!
cheat 2 used!
cheat 1 used!
```

[Live demo](http://ideone.com/QB725)

Comment: Jumping into a project and realizing how much you suck is the first step to learning. I'm going to examine this very carefully and implement something like it. Cheers. +1

Comment: You might be interested in this [stack-exchange proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/11464/code-review?referrer=aWNm_PdciyFqjFW8CUacGw2 "code review"). It's almost ready to begin beta, just needs a few more.

Answer (score 2):

I would store the strings in a trie:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie

(in the Wikipedia article there are also links to C++ implementations).

In the leafs of the trie you can add additional data concerning the cheat.

When you lookup a string you simple check whether the string is contained in the trie with the cheat codes. If yes, you get the additional data (for example a function pointer to a function that does what you want to do; or more Object-Oriented: a pointer to a class instance that when you call one of its member functions does the "cheating stuff").

Comment: From what I can tell, what I have is actually more efficient than this because it just trims a string and does a direct comparison, I'm not sure if I need something like this, but thanks for taking the time to give me some reading material, +1.

Comment: Maybe it depends on where you want your efficiency. This looks very efficient at looking up whether you have matched your cheeat code or not, because it only has to compare the character you pressed on each keypress, not whole strings. It could be worse in terms of memory usage and time to implement.

Comment: Of course, in your case the speed and memory efficiency are likely to be completely irrelevant, and since this is a learning exercise, it all boils down to whether you'd like to learn about a 'trie' :-)

Comment: Both excellent points gentlemen. I will take some time to learn about these bad boys soon.

Answer (score 2):

This code can be improved in several ways.

### Make your immutable strings const static

```
static const std::string const foo[] = { "1taehc", "2taehc", "3taehc" };
```

So they don't have to be allocated every time in your "KeyPressed" handler.

### Associate each cheat with a value that you can use in a `case` statement

I don't think all the additional logic to facilitate the `switch` is a good idea. What about something like this:

```
const int CHEAT_ONE = 1;
const int CHEAT_TWO = 2;
const int CHEAT_THREE = 3;

static const std::pair<std::string, int> const foo[] = { 
    std::make_pair("1taehc", CHEAT_ONE),
    std::make_pair("2taehc", CHEAT_TWO),
    std::make_pair("3taehc", CHEAT_THREE),
};
```

This way you get an integer which you can use as a case label for each of your cheat codes.

### Search for the cheat to activate

You want to be able to search for a cheat code that has been activated easily. Let's break up the `std::pair` instances and use a `std::map` instead.

```
const int CHEAT_ONE = 1;
const int CHEAT_TWO = 2;
const int CHEAT_THREE = 3;

std::pair<std::string, int> cheatcodes[] = {
    std::make_pair("1taehc", CHEAT_ONE),
    std::make_pair("2taehc", CHEAT_TWO),
    std::make_pair("3taehc", CHEAT_THREE),
};

std::map<std::string, int> cheatmap(
    cheatcodes, cheatcodes + sizeof (cheatcodes) / sizeof (cheatcodes[0]));
```

Now, assuming that `candidate` is your keypress buffer, you can just do

```
auto pair = cheatmap.find(candidate);
if (pair != cheatmap.end()) {
    switch(pair->second) {
        case CHEAT_ONE:
        case CHEAT_TWO:
        case CHEAT_THREE:
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I will have a read up on what you suggested and hopefully learn something. Thanks, +1.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it this way: when pressing some specific button first, for example enter, it would start to fill the cheatBuffer, and after one char was filled in the end of the buffer, it would use that buffer to check if a value of it exists in an std::map. And when that value exists, it would execute a function, which pointer was stored in std::map.

Comment: An interesting approach, the map sounds like a decent idea. Thanks for taking the time to answer, +1.

Answer (score 1):

This might be overkill and too much work, but you could make a finite state machine to handle your key inputs, storing your current state instead of storing a key history. Your starting state 0 represents no applicable keys pressed. A 'c' will put you into state 1, where an 'h' will bring you to state 2, a 'c' will keep you at state 1, and anything else will send you back to 0. So on a given keypress you switch on the current state, and inside of that, switch on the character supplied to see which state you transition into. If it was a final state then execute the cheat and transition back to 0.

Comment: That's a pretty interesting idea, however, considering no useful code would be executed in all but one of the states, it seems way overkill to have a class for each key I have in my cheats. It would also be trouble when you have multiple cheat codes that overlap with letters etc. Interesting idea though, +1.

Comment: @Sam152 Actually, overlapping letters is where the finite state machine can shine, it just becomes a little tricker to work out the transitions. You could also implement it as a transition table in a 2d array, but if you do that you can't have a handy default transition and you need to explicitly list out each transition in the table.

Comment: As far as I can make out, this state machine would be basically a hard-coded implementation of a specific 'trie' data structure (as recommended by Nubok). You might be able to find an existing trie implemntation (or write one) to save from actually creating the state machine (and keep the system more flexible).

Comment: @Tony: If I understand correctly, using a trie would not be quite the same since it would traverse the entire tree from root to leaf on every iteration of the loop. An interesting approach would be combining the state machine and trie ideas, using the normal trie insert, but changing lookup to keep its place on partial matches.

Comment: Agreed. I only glanced at the trie explanation in wikipedia, but the structure seemed to lend itself to keeping its place in partial matches.